# How to increase Sqlite FTS4 snippet size

Tags: sqlite, fts3, fts4

Hi I am using sqlite to do full text search on a number of documents. WHile I've got it working basically but I would very much like to increase/expand the amount of text returned in the snippet, is there a way to increase the size, amount of text that the snippet() returns.
I created my fts table using FTS4, I am running python 2.7 on windows 7

Comment: I have seen the documentation which specifies that the 6 parameter can be used. I have tried a few configurations, but I don't seem to be getting any results. i.e the snippet that comes back remains unchaged just the default number of characters is returned. Anyone with a working example. I have tried SELECT snippet(text, '[ ']', '...',,,,64) FROM text WHERE text MATCH '"min* tem*"' is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_4_2) shows, this can be done with the sixth parameter of the `snippet()` function.

Comment: I found what was my issue. Thanks